# Generate n-gram for a specific column present in mysql db

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, n-gram

I'm writing a code to generate n-grams for every record in the table by reading a specific column.

```
def extract_from_db(inp_cust_id):
    sql_db = TatDBHelper()
    t_sql = "select notes from raw_data where customer_id = {0}"
    db_data = sql_db.execute_read(t_sql.format(inp_cust_id))
    for row in db_data:
        text = row.values()
        bi_grams = generate_ngrams(text[0].encode("utf-8"), 2)
        print bi_grams

def generate_ngrams(sentence, n):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    sentence = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ', sentence)
    tokens = [token for token in sentence.split(" ") if token != ""]
    ngrams = zip(*[tokens[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return [" ".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]
```

I'm  getting the output like:

```
['i highly', 'highly recommend', 'recommend it']
['the penguin', 'penguin encounter', 'encounter was', 'was awesome']
```

I want the output to look like below, can anybody help me to get this.

```
['i highly',
 'highly recommend',
 'recommend it',
 ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

creat another list `all_ngrams`, and keep appending the values to it , using `.extend()`, and finally you will have all the `ngrams` in one list.

Try this :

```
def extract_from_db(inp_cust_id):
    sql_db = TatDBHelper()
    t_sql = "select notes from raw_data where customer_id = {0}"
    db_data = sql_db.execute_read(t_sql.format(inp_cust_id))
    all_ngrams = []
    for row in db_data:
        text = row.values()
        bi_grams = generate_ngrams(text[0].encode("utf-8"), 2)
        all_ngrams.extend(bi_grams)
    print all_ngrams
```